# Differentiating the trace of $X^T A X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, trace

I'm solving an optimization problem whose Lagrangian is:

$$\mathcal L(X) = \operatorname{trace}(X^TAX)-\operatorname{trace}(\Lambda(cX^TX-I))$$

where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the Lagrange multipliers.

I want to take $\frac{\partial \mathcal L(X)}{\partial X}=0$ and solve, but I don't know how to differentiate the trace. The trace operator being used in this way is quite foreign to me; how does one go about (1) finding the derivative and (2) solving for values of a matrix-valued function?

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) link.

Comment: Note that the inner product of matrices $A$ and $B$ is usually defined to be $\langle A, B\rangle = \text{Trace}(A^TB)$. This just the ordinary dot product of the vectors you would get by flattening out $A$ and $B$. So this use of the trace is not so strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this guide - [Practical Guide to Matrix Calculus for Deep Learning](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.304.5533&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and the fact $$\text{trace}(A^TB)=A\cdot B=\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$$
Now using the rules [mostly (6), but also (8), (9) (10) and so on] of matrix differential calculus from the guide we can find that the differential is (assuming $c$ is scalar)
$$d\mathcal L(X)=d(AT\cdot X-\Lambda^T\cdot cX^TX-I\cdot\Lambda)=\\=AT\cdot dX-\Lambda^T\cdot cd(X^TX)=AT\cdot dX-\Lambda^T\cdot(dX^TcX+cX^TdX)=\\=AT\cdot dX-\Lambda^TX^Tc\cdot dX^T-cX\Lambda^T\cdot dX=AT\cdot dX-X\Lambda c\cdot dX-X\Lambda^Tc\cdot dX=\\=[AT-Xc(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)]\cdot dX$$
Using the rule (17) from the guide we see that the needed gradient is
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L(X)}{\partial X}=AT-Xc(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)$$
Equating to zero we get
$$AT-Xc(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)=0$$
$$X(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)=\frac{1}{c}AT$$
Now solutions to this equation depends on $(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)$ - if it is invertible we can set
$$X=\frac{1}{c}AT(\Lambda+\Lambda^T)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Computing gradients is delightfully easy when we use the equation
$$
\tag{1} f(X+ \Delta X) \approx f(X) + \langle \nabla f(X), \Delta X\rangle.
$$

Define $f$ by
$$
f(X) = \langle X, AX\rangle = \text{trace}(X^T AX).
$$
If $\Delta X$ is a small matrix, then
\begin{align}
f(X+ \Delta X) &= f(X) + \langle X, A \Delta X\rangle + \langle \Delta X, AX\rangle + \underbrace{ \langle \Delta X, A \Delta X\rangle}_{\text{negligible}} \\
&\approx f(X) + \langle X, A \Delta X\rangle + \langle \Delta X, AX\rangle \\
&= f(X) + \langle (A^T + A)X , \Delta X\rangle.
\end{align}
Comparing this with equation (1),
we discover that
$$
\nabla f(X) = (A^T + A) X.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the trace/Frobenius product with a colon, i.e. $\;P:Q={\rm Tr}(P^TQ)$

The properties of the trace allow terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&P^T:Q^T &= P:Q \;= Q:P \\
&P:QR &= PR^T:Q = Q^TP:R \\
}$$
Define the matrix
$$B = \tfrac{1}{c} A \quad\implies A = cB$$
Write the Lagragian in terms of this new variable.

Then calculate its differential and gradients.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal L} &= cB:XX^T - c\Lambda:X^TX + I:\Lambda \\
d{\cal L}
 &= cB:(X\,dX^T+dX\,X^T) - c\Lambda:(X^TdX+dX^TX) + (I-cX^TX):d\Lambda \\
 &= c(B+B^T):dX\,X^T - c(\Lambda+\Lambda^T):X^TdX + (I-cX^TX):d\Lambda \\
 &= 2c(BX-X\Lambda):dX \quad+\; (I-cX^TX):d\Lambda \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial X} &= 2c(BX-X\Lambda),\quad
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial \Lambda} = (I-cX^TX) \\
}$$
The second gradient simply recovers the constraint, while setting the first gradient to zero results in an eigenvalue equation.
$$\eqalign{
BX = X\Lambda \\
}$$
where the columns of $X$ are the eigenvectors of $B$ and the elements on the
diagonal of $\Lambda$ are the associated eigenvalues. Since $B$ is symmetric, the $X$ matrix is orthogonal.

Without loss of generality, the above assumes that $(A,B)$ are symmetric matrices. And since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, it is also symmetric.